# Air comming in from door side

Tags: repair, doors, door-frame

I'll try to be the more specific possible but please consider I usually talk French.

I'm not the owner of the place I live, I'm renting it. So something like changing a door is not something I considier that I should change if something goes bad with it. Especially when one of the main prupose of a door is not meet; stopping cold air from coming in. But the owner don't want to change it (waste of time talking with him anyway ; "Costs too much." he'll say - I literally hear him saying it).

So I was wondering how could I fix the fact that yes, my exterior door is closing correctly, but there's a huge and quite considerable amount of air entering by where the metalic piece from my door went into the wall hole.

[image: Where air come from (This is not my door)]

Note: It's not my door, it's an example. Mine have a door lock about 2 inches over the handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general fix for air leaking around a door is known in the US as "weatherstripping".

[image]

Image from: http://www.energyconscious.com/m-d-building-products-door-weather-stripping-white-17-63628.html

It comes in several shapes and sizes, but the basic idea is to fill a gap with a compressible foam that will close an irregular gap and keep air out.  It's good practice to put it all the way around a door.

Comment: Thanks! I'll find that. I'm pretty sure it's lot less expensive than changing the door itself.

Comment: @SimonDugré, I'm assuming it's an older door.  Newer doors are made with weatherstripping, and special replacement strips can be purchased that fit into a slot in the door of the original strips are damaged.  Older doors don't have this, so the adhesive backed kind is cheap and easy to use for that.

Comment: Yeah, this door probably have close to 20 years. Thanks a lot.